# Access Computed Value in subscribable function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When using my view model:

```
function SummaryViewModel (arrayString) {
//------- Attributes -------
var self = this;

self.Claims = ko.observableArray(namesapce.Helpers.subnamespace.ToCollection(arrayString));

self.ShowTable = ko.computed(function() {
    var collection = ko.unwrap(self.Claims());
    return collection.length > 0;
}, this);

self.showWarningPanel = self.ShowTable.Not();
}
```

I am trying to invert the computed value. So either the table will be displayed or a warning message.

I have created the following subscribable function:

```
ko.subscribable.fn.Not = function () {
   return ko.pureComputed(function() {
      var bool = this();
      return !(ko.unwrap(bool));
   });
};
```

However, the value for `this()` does not provide the value of the computed attribute. It instead returns all the objects in the current scope.

Originally I marked the method as `ko.computed.fn` and this also did not return the computed value.

I have been referring to the documentation on the KO website to help build the function.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to pass `this` to the `pureComputed` you're creating inside:

```js
ko.subscribable.fn.Not = function () {
   return ko.pureComputed(function() {
      return !this();
   }, this);
   // ^^^^ Here, you tell knockout to execute the function with `this`
   //      context. Alternatively, you could use the var `self = this`
   //      pattern.
};

var myObs = ko.observable(true);
var invertedObs = myObs.Not();

myObs(false);

console.log("observable: " + myObs());
console.log("inverted: " + invertedObs());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```